# object reference error while using bing maps SOAP services

Tags: .net, soap, bing-maps, object-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

I am using bing soap services in my .net web application and I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error in the Line 74:

```
Line 72:             geom p=null;
Line 73:             string k = input.country + ", " + input.zipCode;
Line 74:             x = p.GeocodeAddress(k);   // HERE
Line 75:             input.lat = x.Latitude;
Line 76:             input.lng = x.Longitude;
```

The class code is as follows:

```
 using thn.GeocodeService;
 public class geom
    {
        public Location GeocodeAddress(string inputAddress)
        {
            GeocodeRequest geocodeRequest = new GeocodeRequest();
            geocodeRequest.Credentials = new GeocodeService.Credentials();
            geocodeRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = "<my bing code>";
            geocodeRequest.Query = inputAddress;
            GeocodeServiceClient geocodeService = new GeocodeServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService");
            GeocodeResponse geocodeResponse = geocodeService.Geocode(geocodeRequest);

            if ((geocodeResponse.Results.Length > 0) && (geocodeResponse.Results[0].Locations.Length > 0))
            {
                return geocodeResponse.Results[0].Locations[0];
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

and the calling part is as follows:

```
        user input;
        Location x;
        geom p=null;
        string k = input.country + ", " + input.zipCode;
            x = p.GeocodeAddress(k);
            input.lat = x.Latitude;
            input.lng = x.Longitude;
```

Now where could i have been wrong? And also i have added the geocode services to my project's service references, so thats not a problem..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Almost all cases of NullReferenceException are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: Seriously? Your code is basically `geom p=null;x = p.GeocodeAddress(k);`. It's the same as doing `x = null.GeocodeAddress(k);`. That has nothing at all to do with Bing maps!

Answer (score 0):

You need create a new instance of the geom class. You aren't instantiating p. p is null.
Try

`geom p = new geom();`